# Can a Postgres daterange include infinity as an upper bound?

Tags: postgresql, date-range

I can't see how to create a daterange with `infinity` as an inclusive upper bound. Postgres converts both inputs to an exclusive upper bound:

```
create table dt_overlap (
    id serial primary key,
    validity daterange not null
);

insert into dt_overlap (validity) values
    ('["2019-01-01", infinity]'),
    ('["2019-02-02", infinity)');

table dt_overlap;
 id │       validity
────┼───────────────────────
  1 │ [2019-01-01,infinity)
  2 │ [2019-02-02,infinity)

select id,
    upper(validity),
    upper_inf(validity),
    not isfinite(upper(validity)) as is_inf
from dt_overlap;

 id │  upper   │ upper_inf │ is_inf
────┼──────────┼───────────┼────────
  1 │ infinity │ f         │ t
  2 │ infinity │ f         │ t
```

That both values give the same results is kind of expected, since the inclusive upper bound `infinity]` was coerced to an exclusive upper bound `infinity)`.

The same problem does not exist for the lower end of the range since the daterange keeps an inclusive lower bound and thus `lower_inf()` returns `true`.

Tested and reproduced with Postgresql 9.6.5 and Postgresql 10.3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of creating an unbounded range is to leave out the upper bound completely, e.g. `'["2019-01-01",)'`

```
with dt_overlap (validity) as (
values
    ('["2019-01-01", infinity]'::daterange),
    ('["2019-02-01",]'::daterange)
)
select validity, 
       upper_inf(validity)
from dt_overlap;
```

results in

```
validity              | upper_inf
----------------------+----------
[2019-01-01,infinity) | false    
[2019-02-01,)         | true
```

Comment: It's more than academic. As it stands `upper_inf()` will return false for all possible values (including `infinity`) in a daterange. I find this somewhat counter-intuitive.

Comment: Indeed, `upper_inf('["2019-01-01",)'::daterange)` works... but then `upper('["2019-01-01",)'::daterange)` is null >_< which is in some ways even worse.

Comment: @dland: I wonder why you need to test for the upper (or lower) bound to begin with? What is the use case behind that? I typically only use the "containment" functions and don't bother about the actual values for upper or lower bound

Comment: For date arithmetic. You can't add 1 month or subtract 1 year from infinity in any meaningful way, so you want to guard from doing just that.

Comment: Filed as #15675

Comment: Sorry, I am too late, but this is no bug. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) says: *The `lower` and `upper` functions return null if the range is empty or the requested bound is infinite.*

Comment: Oh, I see. You are complaining about `upper_inf('["2019-01-01",infinity]'::daterange)`. Yes, you have a point there. I looked at the code, and `infinity` is treated as a normal value. I guess it is debatable.

Comment: Yep. Tom Lane said as much in the bug report. Oh well.